# Date comparison in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, date

I want to retrieve all the documents after a particular date.
My database has date as - `DateAdded:"2014-12-17 10:03:46.000Z"`

I wrote the following query-

```
db.collection.find({DateAdded:{"$lte":new Date("2015-06-17 10:03:46.000Z")}})
```

But the results doesn't fetches any record even though there are records for the dates upto `2015-06-24`.

Comment: Your date is in string format. You need to  `save/update` it in IOSDate format to get result from current query.

Comment: It is in date format only.

Comment: Try `"$gte" : ISODate("2015-06-17 10:03:46.000Z")`

Comment: It worked. Thanks. :)  Can you please explain how and why did the earlier one didn't?

Comment: @L_7337 When you add a short explanation of the difference between Date and ISODate you could post this as an answer.

Answer (score 53):

You can use **ISODate** to compare dates:

```
"$lte" : ISODate("2015-06-17T10:03:46Z")
```

**ISODate** works because that is the format your date is in.

```
new Date()
```

wraps the date in an ISODate helper, but is not able to convert in your query.

Check out this link for more information: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/core/shell-types/

Comment: Is there some reason that the Mongo shell allows queries with `Date`, since it doesn't seem to be useful in querying against Mongo date fields?

Comment: broken link, please update

Comment: Which library provides this `ISODate` function?

Answer (score 22):

Use **ISODate**

format:

```
{'field': {$operator: ISODate(yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.msZ)}}
```

example:

```
db.getCollection('yourCollection').find({'sampleField': {$lte: ISODate('2015-06-17T10:03:46.000Z')}})
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use this:

```
db.collection.find({DateAdded:{"$lte":new Date("2017-11-01")}})
```

It will convert your date format into this:

```
ISODate("2017-11-01T00:00:00Z")
```