# what is the best Way to compare dates with MongoDb in asp net core

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I have asp net core application with MongoDB.and I'm saving the date in the format of [dd/MM/yyyy]

```
{"CreatedDate",DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") }
```

whereas CreatedDate is field in the MongoDB .
and i have to compare the saved date with filterDate that i'm sending.
What's the best way to compare the dates with MongoDB?

Comment: Have you tried something? Put it in Quesion

Comment: Have you checked this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071999/date-comparison-in-mongodb

Comment: @Sushantyelpale i have tried wirh MongoDbBuilder like, builder.Where(s => (s.CreatedDate != null && s.CreatedDate >= from_date) but there is error....Not able to compare

Comment: i have already checked the link you have provided[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071999/date-comparison-in-mongodb]...i think its for cmd ,but not with C#

Comment: Is your filterDate in the same format as your CreatedDate? A dd/MM/yyyy string?

Comment: you can try saving the date in integer format like 23rd Oct 2019 into 20191023, you can easily compare it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not store date object as string, you cannot compare to any date variable by this way. Yo should insert your dates like

```
{"CreatedDate", new Date("2017-03-24T17:00:00.832Z")} or {"CreatedDate", new Date()}
```